# Turning on performance breaks Drupal (PHP fatal error)

Tags: performance

I am not certain if I turn on CSS/JS aggregation or caching which breaks Drupal.

The error I get is similar to this:

> 'home/user/mysite.com/commons/includes/includes/bootstrap.inc' does
>   not exist.

I can see that **includes** folder has been repeated twice. When I turn off (by overwriting the whole database) **performance** the problem is fixed.
I have also tried to truncate the cache tables with no effect.
Is this something that someone else has come across?
does anyone know where the performance variables are stored in the MySQL tablesso that when my website breaks I can turn them off from PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Check the permissions for your public directory, usually sites/default/files, perhaps the aggregated files are having trouble being saved?

Comment: Can you disable aggregation, and then turn on caching and see what that gives you? You need to know which one is the culprit (aggregation is unlikely, by the way). And you are also certain that the Drupal code is clean? You didn't hack it somewhere? Because that double includes/ is very suspicious. Oh yeah, the variable is called "cache" and is a boolean (1 or 0). It's stored in the "variables" table. But because Drupal stores variables as Blobs, you may have a hard time editing it using PHPMyAdmin...

Comment: Hi Wadmiraal, as far as I can see, there is no "variable" table in my database, can you confirm?

Comment: I also confirm that enabling CSS aggregate, breaks the site on IE and FF, works fine on Chrome.